# F# and SVCUTIL Error: There was an error trying to generate code in the specified language

Tags: f#, wsdl, svcutil.exe

Got error: 
CodeMethodMember must not have both ImplementationTypes and PrivateImplementationType set.
when running svcutil.

C:>svcutil /language:"Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom.FSharpCodeProvider, FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom, Version=2.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a19089b1c74d0809"  http://localhost/webservices/CoreService.svc?wsdl

Microsoft (R) Service Model Metadata Tool
[Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Communication Foundation, Version 3.0.4506.2152]
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Attempting to download metadata from 'http://localhost/webservices/CoreService.svc?wsdl' using WS-Metad
ata Exchange or DISCO.
Generating files...
Error: There was an error trying to generate code in the specified language.
This could be because the language does not support all the code elements being generated. Consider using another langua
ge.

```
CodeMethodMember must not have both ImplementationTypes and PrivateImplementationType set.
```

Have F# 2.0 installed including the PowerPack, GAC contains the necessary DLL's.

CodeMethodMember is generated by generator.fs (search with Google for CodeMethodMember).

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that the F# CodeDom is rich enough for svcutil (though I don't know much about the F# CodeDom).  You might generate C# code, compile it into a DLL and reference that DLL from your F# application.

Comment: I forgot to mention that Svcutil for C# delivers a CoreService.cs file of 400 kb with more than 9.000 lines of code. A bit too much to rewrite it to F#.

Comment: Compiling C# into a DLL is a workaround that I will do, after I (others???) find out that it is impossible with F# (libs).